# jQuery post upload file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a image upload form which adds an image to my server, although I'm wanting to load the information through jQuery ajax so the form doesn't refresh on submit.

At the moment I have

```
     $('.img-form').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.post(document.href, $(".img-form").serialize());

});
```

Which seems to post the document, although i need to get it to call my ImageUpload() function from the PHP once I've pressed the submit.

My php function is called something like this,

```
<?php $Users->TutorialImageUpload(); ?>
```

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

Comment: @Bishop: I think his problem is related to the fact that uploading files is not possible by XHR this way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you wish to upload an image without refreshing the page, and call your imageUpload() function.

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot upload in such a manner, however, what you could do
is put your upload form and code in a seperate php file and include it in the page as an iframe. This would upload your files withough refreshing the page.